# possibility of setting an axis break in R

Tags: r, axis

Is it possible to set a break on logarithmic axis?
I need to start x axis from 0.2.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Shape, colour=ss))+stat_ecdf(geom="point")+
scale_x_continuous(trans='log10')+
scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')
```

Thanks for your time and kind help. :)

[image]

Comment: try looking up the `limits` argument in `scale_x_continuous()`

Comment: limits in ecdf cuts off the data changing the ecdf estimate (unless this has changed), I recommend setting the y limit in coord_cartesian